# Accessing objects within switch statements

Tags: java, ajax, switch-statement, logic

I currently am stuck as to what the most efficient way is to fix this issue. My current goal is to code for a button click on a page.

If the user meets a certain number of requirements, a message will appear on a certain tab. If they are interested in what the message has to offer, they will click a recalculate button which will then do some behind the scenes calculations and display a different version of the message.

Right now the original message has all of the logic in one particular case within a switch statement. My question is what is the best way to take this object that has the users data and bring that to another case statement.

Below is the code I currently have:

```
public final AjaxResponse pageLevelOnAjaxEvent(final String event, final 
HashMap<String, String> parameters) {
    final AjaxEvent ajaxEvent = AjaxEvent.translateEvent(event);
      switch (ajaxEvent) {

      case EXAMPLE:

        final InfoObject test = new InfoObject(Keys.get(Keys.KEY_RANDOM));


        final InfoObjectResponse objectResponse = test.generateInfo(get400RuntimeData(), getApplication());


        ajaxActions.addAll(infoView.updateView(test, objectResponse, string, string2, "735"));
            break;

        case BUTTON_CODE:
            break;

}
```

My problem is that whenever I click the button to start the `BUTTON_CODE` event, the `test` and `objectResponse` objects are back to null even though they run the methods in the `EXAMPLE` event.

I'd really like to not have to re run the methods that I run in the EXAMPLE event and I shouldn't have to because those objects are already filled.

My question is how do I access that data within the BUTTON_CODE event? If I declare the object within the ajax method that this is a part of, it will always be null when the BUTTON_CODE event is activated because it has to be initialized and thus will always go back to that value.

So what is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make them class variables.